# Mounting remote directory into container running on kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sshfs

I have a container running on a kubernetes cluster. I would like to mount a remote directory into this container. I have read that a docker plugin sshfs can be used for it. Is there another way to do that e.g. with sshfs directly running on the container without installing the docker plugin?
I would like to have the container running with the remote directory mount. A service running on the container would scan the directory and under some conditions, the service would handle the files found in this directory.
I'm not an operations expert and I have questions regarding accessing the remote directory from the microservice running in the container and pod.
I would apreciate any hint.

Comment: Instead of depending on "files" as the main way to interact with your application, can you HTTP POST the data into the container, or use a job queue like RabbitMQ?  Shared filesystems in a distributed cluster environment like Kubernetes can be tricky to manage.  (Do read the Kubernetes documentation on [volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/), though.)

Comment: Hi. The files will be images or videos. Sending them over HTTP is not an option. They can be updated from time to time and it should be done automatically without a big fanfare from the other applications providing these files. Using RabittMQ will be a constraint for old applications etc., and sending messages with videos as a payload sounds not right in this use case. Thanks anyway for replying and hints.

Comment: @Rubén If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Hi @SaiChandraGadde. We decided to make the Integration not over ftp. Thus, there is no resolution of it.